# How to first get a specific row by id and after order the rest alphabetically by specific column

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am trying to get a specific id (53) to be first in order when retrieving my data and after that order `title` alphabetically. I found some answers here but none were what I am looking for.

Currently this is my query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM snm_categories 
WHERE parent_id = ".$conn->real_escape_string($getcat['id'])." 
AND published = 1  
ORDER BY CASE WHEN id = 53 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, id, title
```

This correctly shows the first result with id 53 but the remaining items are not ordered alphabetically by `title`. How can I do that?

Comment: Remove the second `id` in your `ORDER BY`. This is forcing to sort by `id` first and then `title`

Comment: Thats because you order the rows by 1. `WHEN id = 53` 2. `id` and only then by 3. `title`. Remove the 2. `id`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN id = 53 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, title, id,
```

You have to change the sequence of the fields. You write the title column first  before the id column.  It matters.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL treats boolean values as numbers, with "1" for true and "0" for false.

So, you can simplify the logic to:

```
ORDER BY (id = 53) DESC, title, id
```